Passing information from 'before' to 'after' block
(I'm using JRuby, but I think that my problem applies to MRI Ruby as well)
My RSpec definition has this overall structure:
RSpec.describe 'XXX' do
  before(:all) do
    # preparation common for each example
  end
  after(:all) do
    # clean up after each example
  end
  context 'C1' do
    it 'Ex1' do
      ....
    end
    it 'Ex2' do
      ....
    end
    ....
 end
 context 'C2' do 
   .... # more examples here
 end

end
The problem here is that the preparation work (before(:all)) involves calculating a value, say
some_value=MyMod.foo()

which I would need in the cleanup code (after(:all)), i.e.
MyMod.bar(some_value)

Of course, since some_value is a local variable, I can not do this. In theory, I could use a global variable,
 before(:all) do
   $some_value=MyMod.foo()
 end
 after(:all) do
   MyMod.bar($some_value)  
 end

but this is not only ugly, it would cause problems if I decide one day to parallelize my tests.
Can this be achieved? Or is my overall design flawed?
UPDATE : As requested in a comment, I explain here why I want to do this:
Our application has a set of global properties (technically speaking, they are stored in a global singleton object), and these "properties" are set to default values according to the specification of this application, i.e. in the normal case, they are never changed. However, for purpose of experimentation, it is possible to override these properties during startup of the application (via environment variables).
Hence the vast majority of RSpec tests just use those defaults. However, some unit tests also are supposed to test the case where these properties have a value different from the default. Currently I write the examples so that at the start of the example, I store the current test of the property in a variable, and at the end of the exmple set the porperty back to the original value. If I want to do this for a set of examples, which are scoped in the same describe or context block, I thought it would be better to do this change-and-reset of the variables in a before or after block, so that it is done uniformly in all examples in this group.

You can use instance variables as shown in the docs for before and after hooks, e.g. @some_value

Don't use globals. Generally, used scoped :let or instance variables that will clean themselves up. If you really need something explicitly in both :before and :after that won't pass properly, use :around hooks instead.

On a side note, please give us a real example of what you're trying to do. I suspect you're not properly leveraging scopes, which is a common problem for people used to xUnit tests that need explicit setup and teardown instead of garbage collection, as well as languages that don't have Ruby's flexibility with lexical scopes, bindings, and scope gates.

Do not use before(:all) or after(:all) unless you have an extremely strong reason to do so. It's an easy way to get flapping tests, test ordering issues etc. Use let/let! for dependencies and before(:each) for proceedural test setup steps.

As already noted by Stefan in the comments, you can use instance variables for this.
Specifically, each RSpec example group (i.e. describe or context block) defines a class, and any examples (it, example, specify, etc.) and hooks (before, after and around) in the group are evaluated in the context of an instance of that class.
Thus, as the documentation shows, you can define an instance variable (which will belong to that instance of the example group class) in a before block and access it from any it or after blocks in the same group (or in nested groups, which inherit hooks from their parent groups), e.g. like this:
describe 'something' do
  before(:each) do
    @some_value = MyMod.foo()
  end

  after(:each) do
    MyMod.bar(@some_value)  
  end

  # Add your examples here...
end

(You can also use before(:all) and after(:all) here, in which case the hooks are only executed once for the entire example group, rather than before and after each example in the group.  Other than that, they work exactly the same.  Note that before(:suite) hooks, however, can not be used to define instance variables like this, since they are evaluated differently.  In general, I'd recommend just not using them.)

An alternative solution is to use the let! to define a memoized helper method that (because of the !) is automatically evaluated before any examples, and whose saved value is still available later:
describe 'something' do
  # This is evaluated in an implicit before hook before each example:
  let!(:some_value) { MyMod.foo() }

  after(:each) do
    MyMod.bar(some_value)  
  end

  # Add your examples here...
end

One advantage of this approach (besides arguably cleaner syntax with less @ signs) is that some_value cannot be reassigned in examples (which could lead to subtle bugs).  However, its contents may of course still include mutable objects, so this does not perfectly guarantee that the settings restored in the after block are still the same as what they were before the examples.
Also, while you can set multiple instance variables in a single before block, let! only lets you define one helper method.  Of course you could always work around that limitation with something like this:
describe 'something' do
  let!(:saved_settings) do
    some_value = MyMod.foo()
    other_value = MyMod.foo2()
    [some_value, other_value].freeze
  end

  after(:each) do
    some_value, other_value = saved_settings
    MyMod.bar(some_value)
    MyMod.bar2(other_value)
  end
end

One more (minor) limitation of this approach is that let! is evaluated before each example, so you cannot have it evaluated only once per example group like before(:all).  However, it's generally good practice to clean up the environment after each example anyway, so in practice this isn't as much of a limitation as it might seem.

Yet another solution, already suggested by Todd A. Jacobs in the comments, is of course to use an around hook instead:
describe 'something' do
  around(:each) do |example|
    some_value = MyMod.foo()
    example.run
    MyMod.bar(some_value)  
  end

  # Add your examples here...
end

Arguably this is the neatest and most flexible method.  However, it does have the same limitation as let! in that the hook will always be executed once for each example; there's no support for around(:all) hooks in RSpec.  At least not without additional third party gems.
(Disclaimer: I have not tested the gem linked above, I just found it with a quick Google search.  However, at a glance the code looks solid, even if it hasn't been updated for a decade.)

Ps. One common situation that resembles your example is where you want to change the value of a Ruby constant before your tests (e.g. to toggle a feature flag, replace a config setting or even mock an entire class) and restore its original value afterwards.  For that, RSpec Mocks provides a specific solution in the form of the stub_const method:
describe 'something' do
  before do
    stub_const('MyMod::FOO', 42)
  end

  # Add your examples here...
end

The code above ensures that MyMod::FOO will have the value 42 within your examples, while also automatically restoring its original value after each example.  Note that you don't even have to define an after hook for restoring the constant to its original value, since RSpec Mocks takes care of that automatically.
You can also call stub_const directly from an example (it / example / specify) block, which reduces boilerplate code even further if you only need the constant stubbed for a single example (or if you need to give it different values in different examples).

Why would you even need to setup multiple variables in a single let block? You could just write let(:foo){ MyMod.foo()}; let(:bar){ MyMod.bar()}; and it would use the exact same number of lines. Of course if your  test dependency is a list of things an array might be more suitible.

@max: It's occasionally useful. Looking at the legacy codebase I work with, there's a lot of test setup code that looks something like before { Database.perform_transaction { |trx| @foo1 = trx.insert(:foos, id: 'FOO1'); @bar1 = trx.insert(:bars, id: 'BAR1'); @foobar1 = trx.insert(:foobars, foo: @foo1, bar: @bar1, value: 42); } }. Such code could be broken up into multiple let! statements, but doing that naively would require breaking up the DB setup into multiple transactions, which would slow down our already slow test suite even further.

(FWIW, we've since written a custom RSpec extension that lets us write such database test fixture definitions in a cleaner way, using syntax very similar to let!, and have them all committed in a single transaction behind the scenes. But a lot of the legacy tests were written before that feature was added.)

That is a pretty specific example.

Thanks a lot for the explanation. Just a question about correct terminology: An example is something defined with it. Is an example group then the set of all examples inside a context, or maybe inside a describe?

@user1934428: Yes, that's the terminology RSpec uses. Each describe or context block defines an example group, containing one or more examples defined with it or describe (or various other aliases, see the documentation for details) and possibly some hook definitions (before, after, around) as well as e.g. method definitions (using plain old def; remember that example groups are classes). Of course example groups can also contain other nested example groups, which will inherit any hooks and methods from their parent group(s).

@IlmariKaronen : I see. But you say "examples defined with .... describe". Does it mean that I can also put my expect commands directly into a describe block? If so, what do I then need it for?

@user1934428: Ah, sorry, that's a (repeated) typo. I accidentally wrote describe when I meant specify, which is an alias for it. I've edited my answer to fix that, but I can't edit my comment above anymore. :(

May I ask you why you are freezing the array in [some_value, other_value].freeze? It is to protect save_settings from accidentally be modified?

@user1934428: Yes. You might consider that an unnecessary precaution, but since I had just mentioned unmodifiability as one advantage of let! over instance variables, I didn't want my work-around to ruin that advantage.

I'm going to say your overall design is probally flawed.
before(:all) is a feature in RSpec that should be avoided except in very special cases.
If what you're facing is one of those rare cases where the performance benefits of performing your test setup once per spec outweighs the downsides and risks of shared state than you can use instance variables to store a variable for the entire spec.
Like in this web scraper example I shamelessly stole from Myron Marston:
describe "Scraping page X" do
  before(:all) do
    @scrape_summary = MyScraper.perform_on("http://foo-bar.com/bazz")
  end

  it "extracts one kind of thing from the page" do
    @scrape_summary.total_results.should eq(25)
  end

  it "extracts something else from the page" do
    @scrape_summary.link_urls.should include("http://some-expected-url.com/")
  end

  # ...several more of these sorts of examples
end 

Here by doing the HTTP call and parsing steps once the tests run significantly faster. It's also critical here that each example is 100% side effect free and doesn't alter @scrape_summary.
For all other use cases you should be using let and let! to setup test dependencies and setup/teardown per example. This avoids inter dependencies between your examples and the dreaded "flapping" example. They are also thread safe.
RSpec.describe 'Thingy' do
 # The dependencies of our example group which are memoized per example
 let(:foo) { Foo.new }
 let(:bar) { Bar.new }

 # do this before every example
 before do
   some_proceedural_step(foo)
 end

 # tear down if needed
 after do
   undo_some_proceedural_step
 end

 it "frobnobs the whatchamacallit" do
   # ...
 end

 context "when foo is awesome" do
   # let can be refined per example group
   let(:foo) { Foo.new(awesome: true) } 

   it "superfrobnobs the whatchamacallit" do
     # ...
   end
 end 
end


(1) What is the scope of this instance variable, i.e. which class is it in? Do I have a separated instance for each describe? (2) In what respect is a plain before different from a before(:all)?

Instance variables in Ruby do not actually belong to a class. Rather the scope is whatever self is at the time of definition. In RSpec describe can yield different classes. But I would say the scope is the example group. If you want to check set a breakpoint.

before ( and after) with no arguments is the same as before(:each) which is what you should be using 99.99% of the time.
